# absolute convergence of difficult series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Take a look at $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}{n\cdot \sqrt[6]{n^5+n-1}}$. Does this series converge and maybe also converge absolutely? What i did find out is that $\dfrac{1}{n^2} < \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}{n\cdot \sqrt[6]{n^5+n-1}} < \dfrac{1}{n}$ which helps me not at all. I also tried quotient test and root test which gave me 1 so they dont help ether. Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

we have

$$u_n\sim \frac {n^{\frac {2}{3}}}{n.n^{\frac {5}{6}}}  \; (n\to \infty)$$

or

$$u_n\sim \frac {1}{n^{\frac {7}{6}}   }$$

$\sum u_n $  converges absolutely.